# How do I get my non MSTest unit tests running on .net 4.0

Tags: unit-testing, .net-4.0

Has any of the alt.net unit testing frameworks embraced .net 4.0 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NUnit](http://nunit.org/) 2.5.5 includes support for .NET 4.0:

> NUnit 2.5.5 release is updated to work
>   with the final release of .NET 4.0 and
>   provides additional capabilities in
>   defining theories.

---

The latest [MbUnit (bundled with Gallio)](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/11/announcing-gallio-v31-update-2.html) (v3.1 Update 2) supports up to .NET 4.0 Beta 2:

> This releases fixes several problems
>   on x64 platforms and includes support
>   for Visual Studio 2010 and .Net
>   Framework 4.0 Beta 2.